# CakePHP Ajax Image Upload

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, image-processing, file-upload

How can i submit a form which contains an image and store it in img/orginal folder and then resize it to a few different sizes and store them in img/small img/medium img/large using the CakePHP media plugin or any other plugin.

I just want to know is it possible to upload an image by sending the file to the server and running an action where i can do a little bit of logic and return back and display the image.

Please guide me where i should start.

Comment: Found this http://pixelcone.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-using-jquery-and-cakephp-media-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.uploadify.com/

is fine for jquery. 
I'm not experienced with cakephp through

Comment: i had a look into that component.. looks awesome. just trying to undeerstand how to implement it in Cake

Comment: Put the whole uploadify package in `app/webroot/uploadify`, paste the [Head section](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) into a view and change the `script` setting to point to a CakePHP controller action that handles the upload..

Answer (score 1):

you can always create your own component or you can use a component from the bakery page. I've found this two that might help you

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/floorball92/2009/08/02/image-component-for-upload-and-thumbnail-phpthumb

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/santoshgroup/2010/10/12/file_upload_restriction_2

Good Luck!

Comment: ahhh oops didnt see the "AJAX" in the title.. so you should use a JS uploader like the one mentioned on the other answer, and server side you'll need a component like the ones that i sended you

Answer (score 1):

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Warringer/2009/05/08/comfortable-ajaxuploads-with-cakephp

It doesn't work with the latest version of CakePHP, but I think its close to what you need.

[UPDATED, March 13 2012]

Actually, I was looking for something like the above (which is how I stumbled on this Stackoverflow post in the first place), and didn't really find anything that came close to what I was looking for ... so wrote my own Plugin:

https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload

All documentation is in the README, and it should just work out of the box on CakePHP 2.0.6 and 2.1.0 (tested on both.) Hope its useful.